# ubuntu error when reboot (load kernel modus)

Tags: boot

I have a raspberry pi 3b with ubuntu mate every time I restart the grater I get an error message on the screen (emergency mode):

Failed to start Load kernel modules
Does anyone know what I can do about it? 
Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Please delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have downloaded the image file completely without problems & write to the media without cause a error.
you can check the memory card for disk errors with this command in emergency mode:

```
sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

after checking badsectors you can reboot with type "`reboot`" command in bash/sh

if you are using emulator of raspberry pi 3, you need to make a custom command for boot linux kernel:

in grub:

```
linux (X0,Y1)/path/to/kernel7.img
```

in emulator (for example "qemu")

in command line : `-append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 console=tty1"`

if all is not, & the error still is, write the os again into USB/sdcard media.